# SQL select based on non-null values in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am making a scheduling tool for an engineering firm. There is a manager for each engineering discipline, and these managers need to be able to see the jobs that their discipline has been assigned to. A job may have two or more disciplines working on it.

I have two tables. One is a list of all of the active jobs being worked on at the company. It has the fields

```
ID | Job Name | Civil | Mechanical | Electrical |  more disciplines...
```

The columns with the discipline names would hold numerical values for the budget alotted to that discipline for that project.

The other table is for all the users in the system (the managers):

```
Name   |   Discipline
```

The Users table would have entries with a manager's name, then their discipline, such as "Civil". This Civil manager would be able to see all the jobs that have a non-null value in the Civil budget column.

How would I go about selecting the applicable jobs? I think I'd need to check the Users.discipline value of the logged-in user,

```
SELECT discipline FROM Users WHERE name = logged-in-username
```

But I don't know how to compare that value to whether or not there is a non-null value in a column with the same name in a different table.

If you have an idea on how to restructure these tables to better accomodate queries like this, I'm all ears.

Using SQL-Server 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are really open to restructuring your tables, I would recommend this:

```
** PROJECTS **
PROJ_ID |Project_Name
1   Project A
2   Project B
3   Project C

** PROJECT_BUDGETS **
PROJ_ID |Discipline |Budget
1        Civil       $4400
1        Mechanical  $2200
1        Electrical  $1200
2        Civil       $7600
2        Electrical  $1600
3        Materials   $3500

** MANAGERS **
MGR_ID|NAME    |DISCIPLINE
1      Bob      Civil
2      Frank    Mechanical
3      Amy      Electrical
```

To get a list of projects, you could use:

```
SELECT p.PROJECT_ID, b.BUDGET
FROM PROJECTS p LEFT JOIN PROJECT_BUDGETS b ON p.PROJ_ID = b.PROJ_ID
WHERE b.Discipline = (stored value from your logged in user's discipline)
```

Comment: I'd add in a "lookup" table for Disciplines, but otherwise, yep.

Comment: I agree, I would too. I kept it a little simple for this example, but that is exactly where you want to go with it.

Answer (score 3):

You are storing your job data in a pivoted structure. This does make certain kinds of queries a little trickier. However, it isn't too difficult to unpivot your data as a sub-query. Said sub-query can then be more easily joined to solve your problem.

Imagine your schema stored budgets in a separate table as follows:

```
JobId  Discipline Budget
-----  ---------- ------
1      Civil         100
1      Mechanical     50
2      Mechanical     25
2      Electrical     50
```

Then your query would be:

```
declare @CurrentUser int = ?

select  ...
from    Jobs j
where   j.JobId in (
        select  j.JobId
        from    JobBudgets b
                inner join Users u on
                    u.Discipline = b.Discipline
        where   u.UserId = @CurrentUser
        )
```

So then, the next question is how to unpivot your existing `Jobs` table. I'll demonstrate using a CTE which can then be easily used with the above query.

```
;with JobBudgets as (
    select  JobId, 'Civil' as Discipline, Civil
    from    Jobs
    where   Civil is not null
    union all
    select  JobId, 'Mechanical', Mechanical
    from    Jobs
    where   Mechanical is not null
    union all
    /* Repeat for each Discipline */
)
select  ... /* This is where you plug in the previous query */
```

Note that sql server does also support [unpivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) syntax. Feel free to experiment with that as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an INNER JOIN from table1 to table2 WHERE table2.value IS NOT NULL
An example would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
INNER JOIN Jobs ON Jobs.ID = Users.job_id
WHERE Jobs.<job_name> IS NOT NULL
```

Note that you should adjust it to your situation and that  here is a variable where should go the name of the job.

To make the comparison with null values you need IS NULL or IS NOT NULL depending on what you want.

Comment: `Jobs.<job_name>` is not valid T-SQL syntax.

Comment: Users.job_id is not a field in my Users table. Instead, a join would have to be between the user's engineering discipline (Users.discipline) and the _field name_ in Jobs. So a user with Users.discipline = 'Civil' would be able to see all the jobs that have a non-null value in the 'Civil' field in Jobs.

Comment: Pedro, it seems to me you failed to read the question properly. You're likely to attract down-votes unless you delete or fix your answer.

Comment: It was just an example, sorry if that was misleading, will add a claarifications